# Server Running Spam Software

Tags: server

I have an icloud email address that has suddenly become overwhelmed with spam.

Is there any server software(separate external server) that will connect to the icloud server(not installed on my laptop) that will scan it for spam?

I have IMAP access so it should be theoretically possible.

Comment: gmail can act like a pop/imap client I think....